# Checking if a point is inside a rectangle with rounded corners

Tags: javascript, svg

I am looking for a formula, if any to find out if a point is inside a rectangle which has rounded corners.

I am using JavaScript and SVG to draw points in a rectangle of variable height and width and corner radius.

I am looking for something similar to this formula which finds if a point is inside a circle

```
Math.pow((x - centerX, 2) + Math.pow(y - centerY, 2) < Math.pow(r, 2)
```

Comment: Draw the rect then use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint